# PYTHON OR SCILAB: how to turn a image into a matrice?

Tags: python, image, image-processing, scilab

I want to turn a image into a matrice of it's pixel values. For simplicity's sake i want to turn a black and white image to a matrice of black and white values from 0-255, so one value for each pixel in the image.I also want to try to make the image rows and columns corresponds to the image width and height. Can someone please help me. preferably i want to do it in scilab or python.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Scilab have a computer vision toolbox named `scicv` that can help you doing image manipulation (backed by openCV).

For more basic image handling, there is a Scilab demo called `java image` in Graphics / Matplot. This demo load an image using the embedded Java ImageIO library and `getRGB()` value for it to have a Scilab native matrix (stored as uint32 ARGB values).

Read https://gitlab.com/scilab/scilab/-/blob/main/scilab/modules/graphics/demos/matplot/java_image.dem.sce to read the code.